# $_POST['foo'] not working when trying to pass hidden fields from WordPress landing page to checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce within WordPress and have a landing page that submits directly to checkout using:

```
<form action="/checkout/?add-to-cart=1140" name="frm" method="post">
```

I have several hidden fields I'd like to pass to the Woo Checkout page and have them appear below the product item in product details. On the Landing Page, these look like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="webinar1" name="webinar1" value="selected">
```

If this were a normal .php to .php situation (i.e. outside of WP using Woo), I know that something like:

```
$value1 = $_POST['webinar1'];
```

Would retrieve that value and make $value1 = "selected" on the page the form is submitted to.

My issue is that I cannot get the `$_POST['foo']` to work AFTER WordPress has submitted to the Woo checkout using the `/checkout/?add-to-cart=1140` technique.

I have read that this may be a case of variables "disappearing" in WordPress (or becoming otherwise unavailable) once a form is submitted and that some form of

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_attempt' );
function my_attempt() {
// does stuff here
}
```

May be needed, but putting that in functions.php doesn't seem to work when the form action is the

```
<form action="/checkout/?add-to-cart=1140" name="frm" method="post">
```

variety.